# Problems creating a char character with bitwise operations

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to create a char (8 bits) with bit operations, one `hex` at a time. The machine I'm running on is little endian.

So anyways, for example:

```
char buff;
buff = 0x54; // ('T')
printf(" %c \n", buff ); // prints T

buff |= 0x54;        // Produces the same result.
buff |= 0x50 | 0x04; // Produces the same result.
```

BUT I should be able to create the above using bit shifting with `0x5` and `0x4`.

I've tried

```
buff = ((buff << 4) | 0x4) | (buff | 0x5);
```

And variants thereof, but no progress. I feel that I'm missing something simple.

EDIT: Solved.

Thanks all. I never knew you could shift without telling it what to shift*?

- Might not have full understanding on "buff =  0x5 << 4 | 0x4"
  If I interpret it correctly, it shifts 4 to the left, and sets 0x5, then OR with 4?
  ** never mind. Mike below explained what it did thoroughly. Much appreciated all.

Comment: Little and bigendian applies to *full* bytes (`char`), not how each bit is stored within the character.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the reminder. That detail I will have to keep track of in regards of the overall project. But in regards to my question it will be useless then.

Comment: @Xenith Rather than to edit your post, you should accept the best answer of those posted below as correct, by clicking the check mark on the left side of that answer. Then post the text you added through edit as a comment to that answer instead, so that you can hopefully get a reply by the person who answered.

Comment: Heh, new to stackoverflow. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine these steps but here's the break down:

```
char buff = 0x5;  // set the upper nibble of the byte
buff <<= 4;       // shift it over to the left
buff |= 0x4;      // OR in the lower nibble
printf("%x\n", buff);  // result here is 0x54
```

Why your version didn't work:

```
buff = ((buff << 4) | 0x4) ... // start on the left, you shifted nothing 
                               // (if we assume 0 was the starting value). So this 
                               // is just going to be 0x4
buff = (0x4) | (buff | 0x5); // again, if we assume buff is 0 then this becomes 0x5
buff = 0x4 | 0x5;            // (that's 0100 | 0101 which gives you 0x5)
```

Comment: @Xenith - happy it helps. Just remember it never hurts to write it out in more steps, it does tend to help make it more readable.. you can always put it back in one line later.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused about how shifting works, since you're trying to shift the destination before or:ing in a non-shifted constant.

You just need:

```
buff = (5 << 4) | 4;
```

There's no particular point in making these constants hexadecimal, but of course since they each are supposed to be just four bits (one hex digit) it makes a kind of sense although it makes it longer:

```
buff = (0x5 << 4) | 0x4;
```

By the way, the name for "four bits of data" is [a nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) (half a byte, get it?), saying "one hex" makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

The code should not use the value of `buf` in the expression, like this:

```
char buff = ((0x05 << 4) | 0x4);
```

Note that the above expression is a *compile-time constant*, i.e. the `((0x05 << 4) | 0x4)` computation is performed by the compiler, not by the CPU of the target system.

Alternatively, you can do it on several lines, as follows:

```
char buff = 0x00;
buff |= 0x05;
buff <<= 4;
buff |= 0x04;
```

Comment: In the first example, the initial setting is not needed, you don't read `buf` before writing to it in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of you "buff" above would be:

```
buff = (0x5 << 4) | 0x4;
```

Answer (score 0):

shift the first digit left by 4 then or it with the second

```
 int first = 5;
 int second = 4;
 buff = (first << 4) | second;
```